# making global $(this) in inner function in jquery

Tags: jquery

The code I am using is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:button').click(function() {
        var del_val = $(this).attr('name');
        $.post('assets/php/contact_allread.php', {val:del_val}, function(data) {
            $(this).attr('value', data);
        });
    });
});
```

In the above code `$(this)` inside the `$.post` doesn't work. I have to store the value from *contact_allread.php* to the value of the button that the user clicks.

There are many buttons with the same id, so I use `$(this)`. Any solutions?

Comment: don't re-use IDs.  It's not legal HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to cache the `$(this)` outside the ajax call and use that cached variable inside of it,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:button').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var del_val = $this.attr('name');
        $.post('assets/php/contact_allread.php', {val:del_val}, function(data) {
            $this.attr('value', data);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : create a variable `$this` to store `$(this)` instance of button clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:button').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var del_val = $this.attr('name');
        $.post('assets/php/contact_allread.php', {val:del_val}, function(data) {
            $this.attr('value', data);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:button').click(function() {
        var _this = $(this);
        var del_val = $this.attr('name');
        $.post('assets/php/contact_allread.php', {val:del_val}, function(data) {
            _this.val(data);
        });
    });
});
```